# SQL Server - Check Constraint - Without a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2012, and I have a table which has a column `IDSitesPtoP` (`int`) and it contains a foreign key reference to another table. Call the first table, 'TableA'. The second table, TableB has a column `IDSite` (`int`) which is a primary key for `TableB`.

I would like to have a check constraint on `TableA.IDSitePtoP` which basically confirms that the value provided is present in `TableB.IDSite`, but filtered with a where clause. I believe I could do this with a subquery in the table definition of the column like this:

```
IDSitePtoP int CONSTRAINT CHECK (NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT IDSite FROM TableB WHERE TableB.IsDC=0));
```

Unfortunately this method doesn't seem to work, any idea what I have wrong there?

The error I get is:

> Msg 1046, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
>   Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

Should I be approaching this completely differently, it seems to me that this functionality isn't supported in SQL Server...?

Comment: Just out of interest, why not put the horse before the cart and enforce referential integrity in the first place?

Comment: The main reason is that it won't let me, SSMS errors and says that enforcing integrity will cause loops or something to that effect, which is why I'm trying something else. In reality no one would enter something to cause the loop because it would make zero sense from an information point of view (I suppose a typo could occur though), but I don't seem to have the option to just 'accept the warning and proceed cause I said so!'

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, jut fixing the syntax error doesn't solve the problem:

```
IDSitePtoP int CONSTRAINT CHECK
    (TableA.IDSitePtoP IN (SELECT IDSite FROM TableB WHERE TableB.IsDC=0));
```

Subqueries are not allowed in constraints.  You *could* create a UDF to do this.  But, there is another way that might work, assuming that `IDSITE, IsDC` is unique in `TableB`.  If so, create a unique index and use a foreign key index:

```
create unique index tableB(IdSite, IsDC);

create table . . .
    IDSItePtoP int,
    IsDc = 0,
    foreign key (IDSItePtoP, IsDC) references TableB(IdSite, IsDC)
```

Note that I'm using a computed column for the foreign key constraint.  To be honest, I've never created a foreign key constraint with a constant value, so I'm not 100% sure that will work.

Comment: Interesting idea. IDSite is unique in TableB, so I can guarantee that IDSite,IsDC would be unique. I will try this suggestion, thanks. Sad to hear that subqueries aren't supported in check constraints, but good to know before before I waste more pursuing that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need any check Constraint, because you cannot insert records in foreign key column if that record is not present in Primary Key.

Comment: Hi, the problem there is I do need the check, as I'm trying to validate it against a subset of the primary key field, not the entire primary key field in TableB.

i.e.
Not against:
`SELECT IDSite FROM TableB`
But against:
`SELECT IDSite FROM TableB WHERE IsDC = 0;`